# Codeigniter 3: Update em lote update_batch()

Tags: php, codeigniter

Preciso fazer update em lote em uma tabela, tenho um objeto chamado `$data` como o exemplo abaixo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nota] => 
            [frequencia] => 
            [temaTcc] => 
            [idNotaFreq] => 3416a75f4cea9109507cacd8e2f2aefc
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nota] => 
            [frequencia] => 
            [temaTcc] => 
            [idNotaFreq] => a1d0c6e83f027327d8461063f4ac58a6
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nota] => 
            [frequencia] => 
            [temaTcc] => 
            [idNotaFreq] => 17e62166fc8586dfa4d1bc0e1742c08b
        )
)
```

Faço a chamada no `update_batch()` da seguinte forma:

```
return $this->db->update_batch($table, $data, 'md5(idNotaFreq)');
```

Mensagem de erro que recebo:

> Uma ou mais linhas enviadas para atualização em lote está faltando o índice(index) especificado.
>   Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/cert_emissao/system/database/DB_query_builder.php     Line Number: 2028

Observação: No exemplo deixei somente 3 posições do objeto, e sei que eles estão com alguns atributos vazios, mas tentei preencher todos e mesmo assim persistiu o problema. Os objetos que envio para `update` tem entre **10** e **14** posições no total, tendo chance de alguns atributos estarem vazios (*como o exemplo acima*) ou podendo estar todos preenchidos. No entanto, sempre tenho a chave preenchida `idNotaFreq` que acredito ser o que não pode ficar vazio. O nome da tabela é `nota_freq` (MySQL).

Comment: Os valores dessa tabela são obrigatórios? ou seja, `nota` e/ou `frequencia` e/ou `temaTcc` tem alguma regra no banco que podem ser ou não gravados?

Comment: Nenhum dos 3 são obrigatórios.

Comment: Consegui "resolver" fazendo uma alteração. Eu passava o idNotaFreq na clausula WHERE em md5(). Removi o md5() e funcionou.

Comment: Será que o update_batch() não funciona mesmo com md5(), ou eu fiz de forma errada? Com update() uso md5() normalmente.